# insert code keywords inline

Tags: code, inline

What is the command to insert inline code words into the text like this?
[image]

I know there are packages for inserting snippets into the code, but I need to insert keywords within the main text. I was wondering if there is a more convenient way to do that.

Comment: This answer worked well for me https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65291/code-snippet-in-text. Just use "no \texttt{for} or \texttt{while}"

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The package `listings` provides `\lstinline` for such short snippets. The advantage of such a package is its awareness of keywords etc.

In principle any formatting can be used for the 'code' -- as long as the syntax does not interfere with TeX/LaTeX syntax all is well.

The package `xparse` allows for verbatim arguments, it can be used as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\codeword}{v}{%
\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}%
}

\lstset{language=C,keywordstyle={\bfseries \color{blue}}}

\begin{document}

\lstinline{for} or \lstinline{while} or \lstinline{main}

\codeword{Here} you \codeword{see} an \codeword{example} of \codeword{an} inline \codeword{code}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And of course you can specify your preferred font for code snippets in the `\lstset`, not just the colour/weight.

Comment: How do we make this look like Stackexchange syntax highlighting?

Comment: The answer works but it changes the style of the all remaing source text in the document: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/536192/60344.

Comment: `lstinline` can also be used with vertical bars. Example: `\lstinline|os.isfile()|`

Answer (score 36):

This is also possible using the `minted` package and the highlighting tool `pygmentize`

The command for `minted` inline code is called `\mintinline{language}{code}`

The inline highlighting will only colorize keywords, that are defined for the language and colored properly according to the highlighting style you choose.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vs}

\begin{document}
    To create a table you could use the command \mintinline{MySQL}{ALTER TABLE}. 
    While  \mintinline{MySQL}{DROP TABLE} deletes a table,
    \mintinline{MySQL}{INSERT} enables you to insert something into a table.
\end{document}
```

Which gives you:

[image]

Note that the default highlighting style gives you green keywords and you need to use `--shell-escape` to get `pygmentize` to work.

Comment: Beware that installing `pygmentize` on some systems (windows) adds a level of complexity.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator meh, just install Anaconda.

Comment: Some posts that can be helpful if you're having trouble with pygmentize: https://superuser.com/a/1382840/513819 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350523/195804

Comment: does it support bash scripts like: `\mintinline{shell}{echo}`