# lstinline command for inline text code changing the style of all the following text in the latex document

Tags: texmaker, code, inline

I am using TexMaker as editor and in a document I want to put some inline code so I am using `lstinline{}`. The command works but strangely the text of the document after the closing curly bracket is printed in the same font and colour of the text inside the bracket.

For example considering this [mcve]:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{xparse}
\lstset{language=C,keywordstyle={\bfseries \color{blue}}}
\begin{document}
hey \lstinline{for}  asdasda
\end{document}
```

The output is fine, the source text appears as follow:[image] where as you can see the text `asdasda` and even the `\end{document}` are shown as if being part of the inline code.

A partial solution to this is to do `\lstinline{for}\lstinline{}` but it is really confusing and time consuming.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Try to use different delimiters for inline-listings. They have to be the same character. For example `\lstinline+hello+`

Comment: @Wulle it works thanks...if you answer it I will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already stated in my comment: TeXMaker (and every other editor I know) expects the same delimiter for inline listings. If you try:

```
\lstinline+hello world+ or \lstinline|hello world|
```

It should be understood by `\lstinline` and your editor.