# Consecutive colorbox items does not line break in a table

Tags: tables, line-breaking, wrap, colorbox

I want to create a table with the long text content. Each word in the text is color boxed. But when this is done, the text does not wrap and there is no line break. Below is sample code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    1 & {\colorbox[HTML]{f6faff}{this}\colorbox[HTML]{f5f9fe}{is}\colorbox[HTML]{e8f1fa}{an}\colorbox[HTML]{08306b}{apple}\colorbox[HTML]{bad6eb}{that}\colorbox[HTML]{bad6eb}{fell}\colorbox[HTML]{f0f6fd}{from}\colorbox[HTML]{f6faff}{should}\colorbox[HTML]{f6faff}{tree}\colorbox[HTML]{f4f9fe}{and}\colorbox[HTML]{5fa6d1}{broke}\colorbox[HTML]{d5e5f4}{which}\colorbox[HTML]{57a0ce}{made}\colorbox[HTML]{d6e5f4}{me}\colorbox[HTML]{c4daee}{very}\colorbox[HTML]{c4daef}{badly}\colorbox[HTML]{c4daee}{sad}}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I tried the solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312574/colorbox-does-not-linebreak), but that did not work.

Any suggestions on resolving this issue would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: a `c` column type doesn't line break. See here for other column types: https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-08

Comment: I did try with 'p' column type. But I had not given space like pointed out by @F. Pantigny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A column of type `c` is never broken. You should use a column of type `p{...}`.

Moreover, you should add spaces between the `\colorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{6cm}|}
    1 & { \colorbox[HTML]{f6faff}{this} \colorbox[HTML]{f5f9fe}{is} \colorbox[HTML]{e8f1fa}{an} \colorbox[HTML]{08306b}{apple} \colorbox[HTML]{bad6eb}{that} \colorbox[HTML]{bad6eb}{fell} \colorbox[HTML]{f0f6fd}{from} \colorbox[HTML]{f6faff}{should} \colorbox[HTML]{f6faff}{tree} \colorbox[HTML]{f4f9fe}{and} \colorbox[HTML]{5fa6d1}{broke} \colorbox[HTML]{d5e5f4}{which} \colorbox[HTML]{57a0ce}{made} \colorbox[HTML]{d6e5f4}{me} \colorbox[HTML]{c4daee}{very} \colorbox[HTML]{c4daef}{badly} \colorbox[HTML]{c4daee}{sad}}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: or if you don't like visible spaces between the boxes you can add an explicit penalty there so that breaking is allowed, e.g. \colobox{...}\allowbreak\colorbox{...}