# How to define a colorbox command which can treat other user-defined commands in its argument?

Tags: macros, color, expansion, highlighting, colorbox

I would like to highlight text including user-defined commands with linebreaks. I found a solution for linebreaks ([Colorbox does not linebreak](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312574/colorbox-does-not-linebreak/312583#312583)), but the `\ctext{}` command cannot treat other commands in its argument.

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
    
\newcommand{\red}[1]{{\color{red} #1}}
    
\newcommand{\ctext}[3][RGB]{%
   \begingroup
   \definecolor{hlcolor}{#1}{#2}\sethlcolor{hlcolor}%
   \hl{#3}%
   \endgroup
}

%Frame of command '\spec'
\newcommand{\defineSpecies}[2]{\csdef{spec@#1}{#2}}
\newrobustcmd{\spec}[1]{%
  \ifcsname spec@#1\endcsname%
    \csuse{spec@#1}%
  \else
    \GenericError{}{Undefined species `#1'}{}{}
  \fi
}

\defineSpecies{h216o}{H$_2^{~16}$O}

\begin{document}

\ctext[RGB]{0,209,0}{\red{\spec{h216o}}} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you're using LuaTeX use the `lua-ul` package instead of the `soul` package. Else the `ulem` package is more robust than the `soul` package, but inside of `ulem` you get no automatic hyphenation.

Comment: @Skillmon So the `ctext` command cannot be repaired? And what command do you think about in `ulem`?

Comment: well, see `soul`'s documentation, it states a list of stuff that doesn't work (not sure whether that list is exhaustive), in summary: `soul` is not stable and only works for simple stuff. I think `ulem` doesn't have a `\hl`-like command out of the box, but you can define it yourself (you should be able to find examples on this site).

Comment: As @Skillmon wrote: use lualatex and the lua-ul package. Everything else has shortcomings.

Comment: @TobiR Can you give some examples? The question is too generic to receive sensible answers. We now have `\text_expand:n` which might be what you want.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for dealing with this issue. I have updated my question, including an `ifmtarg`-based command.