Latex does not compile after latex texlive update
Excuse me if this is a simple fix, but I cannot find anything on how to solve this.
I updated my texlive packages and the compilation does not work anymore.
I get the LaTeX Error: Loading a class or package in a group.
For many packages like geometry, xcolor, etc…
I don't know how to fix this, as I can't just comment out every package with this error?
I hope anyone can help me and thanks in advance
Edit
This is one example of an error:
./settings/layout.tex:2: LaTeX Error: Loading a class or package in a group.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.2 \usepackage
               {geometry}
Classes and packages should only be loaded at the top level

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry


/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty:31: LaTeX Error: Loading a class or package in a group.

Which is one of many packages which report that error.
Its only third-party packages that throw this error.
preamble:
      \documentclass[
            11pt, 
            a4paper, 
            book,
            oneside,
            openany,  % openany -> on which page should new chapters start
            parskip=half*, % Line spacing for paragraphs
            listof=totoc, % Include listings in the table of contents
            bibliography=totoc, % adding a bibliography to the table of contents
            index=totoc, % add index directory to the table of contents
          toc=chapterentrywithdots, % Set dots in the table of contents also for chapters
          numbers=noenddot, % removes the last dot after X.X.X.
          chapterprefix=true % changes the display of the chapter, adds "Chapter" to the chapter number
        ]{scrbook}
        
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
        \usepackage{url}
        \usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{pdfpages}
        \usepackage{textcomp}
        
        \usepackage{float}
        \usepackage{siunitx}
        \usepackage[nohyperlinks, printonlyused, withpage]{acronym}
        \usepackage{amsmath} % math environment
        
        \sisetup{locale = DE}
        
        % ---------------------------
        % |    Meta-Data for PDF    |
        % ---------------------------
        \usepackage[
          pdftex,
          pdfkeywords={Thesis;Template;LaTeX},
          pdfproducer={LaTeX},
          pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX},
          pdfduplex={DuplexFlipLongEdge}, %Alt.: Simplex or DuplexFlipShortEdge 
          pdflang={de}, % en
          bookmarksopen,
          bookmarksnumbered,
        ]{hyperref}
        
        % ------------------
        % |    Settings    |
        % ------------------
        \input{settings/bibliography.tex}
        \input{settings/graphics.tex}
        \input{settings/tables.tex}
        \input{settings/colors.tex}
        \input{settings/layout.tex}
        \input{settings/listings.tex}
        \input{settings/links.tex}
        \input{settings/commands}
        \input{settings/bookmarks}

settings/layout.tex:
   % geometry
   \usepackage{geometry}
   \geometry{left=25mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=30mm}
   
   \usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
   \pagestyle{scrheadings}
   \automark*[section]{}
   %\ohead{\headmark} % name of the current section
   %\ihead{}
   %\ofoot{\thepage} % page number
   
   % footnote gap
   \addtolength{\skip\footins}{1ex}
   \addtolength{\footnotesep}{0.5ex}
   
   % prevent footnote page break
   \interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
   
   % line spacing
   \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
   
   % text does not have to go to the end of a page
   \raggedbottom
   
   % space before and after chapter headings
   \RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=.6cm,font=\fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont]{chapter}
   %\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=10pt,afterskip=.3cm,font=\fontsize{18}{25}\selectfont]{section}
   %\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=10pt,afterskip=.3cm,font=\fontsize{16}{25}\selectfont]{subsection}
   %\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=.3cm,font=\fontsize{14}{25}\selectfont]{subsubsection}
   
   \usepackage{mwe}
   
   % chapter style
   \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
     \thechapter\enskip
     \textcolor{gray!70}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip}}\enskip
   }
   \setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
   
   % adjust paragraphs
   %\addtokomafont{paragraph}{\itshape}
   %\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\large}
   %\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalsize\itshape}
   \setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalsize}
   
   % layout of the paragraphs
   % paragraphs look like the subsubsections
   \RedeclareSectionCommands[
       beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -0.2ex,
       afterskip=1sp, % smallest possible positive value
   ]{paragraph,subparagraph}
   
   % Bold caption labels
   \setkomafont{captionlabel}{\normalsize\bfseries} 
   % \usepackage[font=sf]{caption} % Captions without serifs

settings/bibliography.tex:
\usepackage[
    backend=biber, 
    style=authoryear-icomp, % alphabetic
    citestyle=authoryear-icomp, % alphabetic, authortitle
    date=short,
    % backref=true, % Display pages on which the reference is used
    maxnames=1, % affects the cites
    maxbibnames=3, % affects the bibliography
    pagetracker=true,
    isbn=false,    
    % block=ragged, % break urls
    % firstinits=true, % shorten first names
    backrefstyle=three+ % Combine pages
]{biblatex}

% Distance between bibliographical references
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{.5em}

% Indentation after the first line
\setlength{\bibhang}{2em}

% URL in the bibliography is in angle brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{<\url{#1}>}

% break too long urls
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}

% Source of the bibliography file
\bibliography{sources/ChangeLiterature.bib}

settings/graphics.tex:
% graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif}

% captions
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

settings/table.tex
% Table layout
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5em} % for the horizontal padding
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % for the vertical padding

% Table captions
%\usepackage{caption} 
%\captionsetup[table]{belowskip=12pt,aboveskip=4pt}
%\usepackage{diagbox}

% Rotate tables
%\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{varwidth}

% Footnotes with tables
%\usepackage{footnote}
%\makesavenoteenv{figure}

% Line breaks in table cells
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}
}

% rotate content of table cell
%\def\rot{\rotatebox} % usage: \rot{angle}{content}

settings/color.tex:

\usepackage{xcolor}

% colors
\definecolor{white}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{middlegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.95,.95,.95}
\definecolor{arsenic}{rgb}{0.23, 0.27, 0.29}
\definecolor{arsenicLight}{rgb}{0.20, 0.20, 0.20}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{.4,.4,.4}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{0.8,0.3,0.3}
\definecolor{yac}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.1}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{.2,0.6,0.3}
\definecolor{azure}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 1.0}
\definecolor{editorGray}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.95}
\definecolor{editorOcher}{rgb}{1, 0.5, 0}
\definecolor{editorGreen}{rgb}{0, 0.5, 0}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.45,0.13}      
\definecolor{olive}{rgb}{0.17,0.59,0.20}
\definecolor{brown}{rgb}{0.69,0.31,0.31}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.38,0.18,0.81}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.57,0.7}
\definecolor{lightred}{rgb}{1,0.4,0.5}

\definecolor{vscodered}{HTML}{E53935}
\definecolor{vscodelightred}{HTML}{EF5350}
\definecolor{vscodeblue}{HTML}{1565C0}
\definecolor{vscodegreen}{HTML}{66BB6A}

\definecolor{lightblack}{HTML}{212121}
\definecolor{darkraspberry}{rgb}{0.53, 0.15, 0.34}

% blue hues
\definecolor{bleudefrance}{rgb}{0.19, 0.55, 0.91}
\definecolor{brandeisblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.44, 1.0}
\definecolor{blue(ncs)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.53, 0.74}
\definecolor{coolblack}{rgb}{0.0, 0.18, 0.39}

% red hues
\definecolor{coralred}{rgb}{1.0, 0.25, 0.25}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.55, 0.0, 0.0}

settings/listings.tex:
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

% name of listings in the toc
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Listingverzeichnis}

% general settings for listing
\lstset{
    xleftmargin=1.1cm,
    belowskip=2em,
    basicstyle=\fontsize{10}{15}\ttfamily,
    basewidth  = {.5em,0.4em},
    captionpos=t,
    lineskip={2pt},
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    framextopmargin=6pt,
    framexrightmargin=0pt,
    framexleftmargin=0.9em,    
    framexbottommargin=6pt, 
    frame=l,
%    frame=single,        
%    frame=tb, framerule=0pt,    
    framesep=6.5mm,
    fillcolor=\color{white},
    rulecolor=\color{middlegray},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\normalfont\color{middlegray},
%    numberstyle=\footnotesize,    
    numbersep=10pt,
    abovecaptionskip=10pt, %space above the caption
    belowcaptionskip=10pt, %space below the caption
    extendedchars=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showspaces=false,
    stepnumber=1, % the step between two line-numbers. If it is 1 each line will be numbered
    tabsize=2,
    breaklines=true,
    showtabs=false,
    upquote=true,
    % German umlauts
    literate=%
    {Ö}{{\"O}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1
    {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1
    {ö}{{\"o}}1
}

% define language
\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
    keywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, then, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break, default},
    keywordstyle=\color{editorGreen}\bfseries,
    ndkeywords={class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this, const},
    ndkeywordstyle=\color{vscodeblue}\bfseries,
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    sensitive=false,
    comment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    commentstyle=\color{editorGreen}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{darkred}\ttfamily,
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]"
}

\lstdefinelanguage{SQL}{
    keywords={select, where, from},
    keywordstyle=\color{editorGreen}\bfseries,
    ndkeywords={},
    ndkeywordstyle=\color{vscodeblue}\bfseries,
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    sensitive=false,
    comment=[l]{--},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    commentstyle=\color{editorGreen}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{darkred}\ttfamily,
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]"
}


\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{
  language=html,
  sensitive=true,   
  alsoletter={<>=-},    
  morecomment=[s]{<!-}{-->},
  tag=[s],
  otherkeywords={
  % General
  >,
  % Standard tags
    <!DOCTYPE,
  </html, <html, <head, <title, </title, <style, </style, <link, </head, <meta, />,
    % body
    </body, <body,
    % Divs
    </div, <div, </div>, 
    % Paragraphs
    </p, <p, </p>,
    % scripts
    </script, <script,
  % More tags...
  <canvas, /canvas>, <svg, <rect, <animateTransform, </rect>, </svg>, <video, <source, <iframe, </iframe>, </video>, <image, </image>, <header, </header, <article, </article
  },
  ndkeywords={
  % General
  =,
  % HTML attributes
  charset=, src=, id=, width=, height=, style=, type=, rel=, href=,
  % SVG attributes
  fill=, attributeName=, begin=, dur=, from=, to=, poster=, controls=, x=, y=, repeatCount=, xlink:href=,
  % properties
  margin:, padding:, background-image:, border:, top:, left:, position:, width:, height:, margin-top:, margin-bottom:, font-size:, line-height:,
    % CSS3 properties
  transform:, -moz-transform:, -webkit-transform:,
  animation:, -webkit-animation:,
  transition:,  transition-duration:, transition-property:, transition-timing-function:,
  }
}

\lstdefinestyle{html} {%
  % Code design
  keywordstyle=\color{lightblack}\bfseries,
  ndkeywordstyle=\color{lightblack}\bfseries,
  identifierstyle=\color{lightblack},
  commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{darkred}\ttfamily,
  % Code
  language=HTML5,
%  alsolanguage=JavaScript,
  alsodigit={.:;},  
  tabsize=2,
  showtabs=false,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,
  breaklines=true,
  % German umlauts
  literate=%
  {Ö}{{\"O}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1
  {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1
  {ö}{{\"o}}1
}

\lstdefinelanguage{CSS} 
{morekeywords={color,background,margin,padding,margin,padding,font,weight,display,position,top,left,right,bottom,list,style,border,size,white,space,min,width,  transition}, 
    sensitive=false, 
    morecomment=[l]{//}, 
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}, 
    morestring=[b]", 
}

\lstdefinestyle{css} {%
  language=CSS,
  keywordstyle=\color{lightblack},
}

\lstdefinestyle{js} {
  language=JavaScript
}

\lstdefinestyle{sql} {
  language=SQL,
  keywordstyle=\color{azure}  
}

%Usage
%\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
%\begin{lstlisting}[style=js, caption={Flux Action Creator}, label=lst:actionCreator] 
%create: function(text) {
  %AppDispatcher.dispatch({
    %type: Constants.TODO_CREATE,
    %payload: 'sample'
  %});
%},
%\end{lstlisting}
%\end{minipage}

settings/links.tex:
% for the links in toc
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
    pdfstartview= % fit zoom size to the viewer
}

settings/commands.tex:
%\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{lightgray}{\texttt{#1}}}
%\lstinline{snippet}
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65291/code-snippet-in-text

% This "\code{my code}" can be used to highlight small code snippets in the text like names of variables or methods.
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\textcolor{black}{\texttt{#1}}}

% The "\todo{this still has to be done}" is a command that highlights todos in the text.
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\textcolor{vscodered}{TODO: \texttt{#1}}}

settings/bookmarks.tex:
% Adding package bookmark improves bookmarks handling.
% More features and faster updated bookmarks.
\usepackage{bookmark}

% \pdfbookmark[<level>]{<title>}{<dest>}

% toc is part of the bookmarks but not part the toc itself
% \pdfbookmark[section]{\contentsname}{toc}


Show your preamble and the log-file until the error.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Without more information, just a note: Loading packages inside a group was always a mistake. Nevertheless I know one package and one class (and I'm almost sure, there are more), which has done this as part of a quick hack. Nevertheless, if you are using such a class or package, you should ask the author to fix this issue, because now LaTeX recognizes this mistake and makes clear, that it is a mistake and always has been. If you are the author yourself, you should also remove the group.

You example starts where it needs to end: we need to see how \usepackage has ended up in a group. So we need to see from \documentclass to the point you get the first error.

try to think a bit. How should we know what is hidden in all this input files?

try to make your example more reasonable; you are asking people to trace it. Delete every line that you can delete while still showing the error.

Ok so i loaded all input files one after the other until it breaks and it works until i load tables.tex, and then it throws the error which i posted about in layout.tex

Your example is completely unreasonable to post here but the error is
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % for the vertical padding

that leading { forces every following package load to be inside a group and give an error.
Simply delete the {.
A more reasonable example would have been
\documentclass{article}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % for the vertical padding

 \usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
text
\end{document}


Thank you this solved it. Now i know for the future what is expected of an example.

@Atem no harm done but especially avoid examples that have \input{something/anything} as even just to run the example requires people to make that directory structure, copy the fragments in to separate files in separate folders and it's just too much effort to expect.
